# Import variable in mapreduce map class

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have an error using mapreduce in Eclypse that I can't understand.

Before mapping some features I need to import a file with already known characteristics (key word) that I want to use to map the new ones. I first import it after the override thing but as I have a lot of lines and as it import it for each map the computation time is very long.
I try to import my variable between the class and the @Override to import it only once and use it after that in the class map but I get the following errors:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text > {

    HashSet<String> word = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                new File("/home/test")));
        String token;
        while((token = BR.readLine()) != null){
            word.add(token); 
        }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

I get after "String token;" the error : 
    Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

after "while" the error : 
    Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead

and after "public void" the error : 
    Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    - overrides

So my question is is it possible to import variable that I want to use in the map class but before the @override? And How can I do that?

---

With the first answers I try to use "public static ..."

```
    public static Set<String> newHashSet(String... strings) {
        HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                new File("/home/test")));
        String token;
        while((token = BR.readLine()) != null){
            words.add(mot);
        }
        return words;
    }
```

But again I get errors.

When I try to read my file I get 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Unhandled exception type 
     FileNotFoundException
        - Resource leak: 'BR' is never closed

And at the while loop 
Unhandled exception type IOException

I just would like to import my file and store the data to use them later in my mapreduce task as a condition.

Comment: Can you post the complete code and the complete stacktrace?

Comment: The while loop is not part of a constructor or method.  That's why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for two important things to jazz up your code.

1. Map provides setUp() Map() and Cleanup() functionality .
2. The functionality can be used for reading some external file in setup ,  ETL the indiviual rows in Map() and cleanup any resources in Cleaup.
3. Distributed cache is a service provided by MR farmework, On driver you distributed the files and the files are available at all dataNodes where Map or Reduce are working.

Please go through the below links for indepth understanding.

Distributed Cache , SetUp() Map and Cleanup()

> 1. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/map-side-joins-in-map-reduce/
> 2. http://bytepadding.com/map-reduce/